# Pushing to an array not working in callback

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback

See the comments in code to see what's actually happening/not happening. Basically within the function, the array.push() method does not seem to work and I cannot wrap my head around why. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
 var locationArray = new Array;

        request(process.env.RESOURCE_SHEET, (error, response, html) => {
            if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

                const $ = cheerio.load(html);
                
                $("h3").each((i, lle) => {
                    const location = $(lle).text();
                    if(location.includes("Kansas")) return;
                    if(location.includes("In Stock")) {
                        var level = location + " ✅";
                    } else {
                        var level = location + " ❌";
                    }
                    locationArray.push(level); // This doesn't push to the array
                });
            } 
        });
        locationArray.push("test") // This pushes to the array

        console.log(locationArray) // Output: "test"
```

Comment: `request` works asynchronously, you should try console the array inside the request callback.

Comment: OMG!!! Thanks so much, that was it.

Comment: @HarshSaini How would you access the array outside of `request`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Harsh Saini.

His response: `request` works asynchronously, you should try console the array inside the request callback.

Working code:

```js
var locationArray = new Array;

request(process.env.RESOURCE_SHEET, (error, response, html) => {
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
            
        $("h3").each((i, lle) => {
            const location = $(lle).text();

            if(location.includes("Kansas")) return;
            if(location.includes("In Stock")) {
                var level = location + " ✅";
            } else {
                var level = location + " ❌";
            }
            locationArray.push(level);
        });
    } 
    console.log(locationArray)
});
```